# Openni or Freenect?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, openni, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm quite new in ROS and I would like to know a general opinion about which one would you use, or which are you using nowadays and why. I would like to use a KINECT to do a SLAM and try to subscribe to topics related with the measured depth.

Thanks everyone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230897/openni-or-freenect?/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2016-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will quote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181332/libfreenect-vs-openni) which I found on Stackoverflow belonging to that question i found as i stood before that decision myself:

> Libfreenect is mainly a driver which
> exposes the Kinect device's features:
>
> - depth stream - IR stream - color(RGB) stream - motor control -
>   LED control - accelerometer
>
> If does not provide any advanced
> processing features like scene
> segmentation, skeleton tracking, etc.
>
> On the other hand, OpenNI allows
> generic access to Kinect's feature
> (mainly the image streams), but also
> provides rich processing features such
> as: - scene segmentation - skeleton
> tracking - hand detection and tracking
>
> - gesture recognition - user interface elements etc. but no low level
>   controls to device features like
>   motor/LED/accelerometer.
>
> As opposed to libfreenect which AFAIK
> works only with the Kinect sensor,
> OpenNI works with Kinect but with
> other sensors as well like Asus Xtion
> Pro, Carmine, etc.

I am using freenect at the moment with success and haven't tried out out OpenNi so long. You can find some info on my projects website [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SfdtqLc7YeuoSwmdOspKt9vbfaUmWDyKpdCXwQvjaXY/edit#heading=h.yio46yi534cc) (in german) and see what i have done so long with my kinect and ROS. Project is still under development.

On point i struggle at the moment is, that the ros-freenect-stack is just supported until ROS-Indigo and i want to update to Jade or Kinectic soon, if someone could help out here please contact me!

Fabian

---

Originally posted by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) with karma: 126 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-04-04**:
Xtion is openni2 only.
Taking a short look at your document you mainly seem to use the kinect for depthimage_to_laserscan, there shouldn't be any problem for you in using openni(2) instead.

**Comment by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) on 2016-04-04**:
I will have a look at OpenNi too, do you have a clue if both drivers work in parallel? In my opinion installing freenect on ubuntu is better documented or easier then OpenNi, or i haven't researched that well enough. Must have a look, cause openni_camera and openni_launch seems better supported

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-04-05**:
I never used freenect, but installing both on the same computer should be no problem. Using both at the same time of course not, openni1 & 2 are packaged, so it should just be a matter of

```
apt-get install libopenni-dev (or libopenni2-dev)
```